# How to splashscreen hold till the response of webclient windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone, webclient

I am developing an app in which i have to make a web request in onlaunching event but it navigates to mainpage.xaml with no data and when the call back of the request is completed then it shows the data . I want to make splash screen stay till the the callback is executed. How to implement this. I have tried doing it by setting a bool variable but it comes that that the call back is also executed on main thread so it does not work properly.

Comment: Be aware that your app needs to be ready after at most 20 second. Otherwise certification will fail!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: i know that but it will not take that much time . i just want that splash screen should stay till that time .. do you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use System.Threading.Thread class to create a new thread. To hold the splash screen you could use

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

where time is in milliseconds. I am not sure if that would allow you to call a web client before the InitializeComponent() constructor is evoked. So other way round is to make a replica of the splash screen as Home.xaml and set the default navigation page to Home.xaml in WMAppManifest.xml. Now call your Web client in the background and navigate the user to MainPage.xaml when the call is completed.